# Solve $\lfloor \frac{2x-1}{3} \rfloor + \lfloor \frac{4x+1}{6} \rfloor=5x-4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, integers

I came across this problem and it doesn't seem so tricky, but I didn't do it.

> Solve the equation
>   $$\lfloor {\frac{2x-1}{3}}\rfloor + \lfloor {\frac{4x+1}{6}}\rfloor=5x-4.$$

My thoughts so far:

Trying to use the inequality $k-1 < \lfloor k\rfloor \leq k$

$5x-4$ is integer, so $x=\frac{a}{5},$ where $a$ is from $\mathbb Z,$ then replace in the original equation, to get
$$\lfloor \frac{4a-10}{30}\rfloor + \lfloor \frac{4a+5}{30}\rfloor =a-4$$
Let $k= \frac{4a-10}{30}$
so $\lfloor k\rfloor +\lfloor k+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor =a-4$

but $\lfloor k\rfloor =\lfloor k+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor $ or $\lfloor k\rfloor +1=\lfloor k+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor $, so we have 2 cases

I strongly think that a shorter solution exists, I would appreciate a hint!

Comment: What is $[k]$? Did you mean $\lfloor k\rfloor$?

Comment: yes, sorry i'll correct it

Comment: your notation is not consistent, either you use $\lfloor \rfloor$ or $[ ]$ in a post (and title) but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lfloor{\frac{2x-1}{3}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\frac{4x+1}{6}}\rfloor=5x-4.$$

As you have been mentioned; 
$5x-4$ must be an integer, 
so $x=\frac{a}{5},$ 
where $a$ is from $\mathbb Z,$ 
then replace in the original equation, to get
$$\lfloor\frac{4a-10}{30}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{4a+5}{30}\rfloor=a-4.$$

---

Notice that by **Euclid's algorithm**
there are integers $n,t \in \mathbb{Z}$; 
such that $a=15n+t$, with $0 \leq t \leq 14$,
by replacing we get that:

$$ 
\lfloor\frac{60n+4t-10}{30}] + \lfloor\frac{60n+4t+5}{30}]=15n+t-4 
\Longrightarrow 
\\ 
2n+\lfloor\frac{4t-10}{30}] + 2n+\lfloor\frac{4t+5}{30}]=15n+t-4 
\Longrightarrow 
\\ 
\lfloor\frac{4t-10}{30}] + \lfloor\frac{4t+5}{30}] -t +4 =11n 
\ 
; 
\ \ \ \ \ 
\color{Blue}{\star} 
$$

---

but notice that $0 \leq t \leq 14$; implies the following inequalities:

$$ 
-10 \leq 4t-10 \leq 46 
\ \ 
%%\text{and} 
; 
\ \ \ 
  5 \leq 4t+5  \leq 61 
\ \ 
%%\text{and} 
; 
\ \ \ 
-10 \leq -t+4 \leq 4 
\ \ 
\Longrightarrow 
\\ 
 \color{Red}{-1} \leq \lfloor\frac{4t-10}{30}\rfloor \leq  \color{Red}{1} 
\ \ 
%%\text{and} 
; 
\ \ \ 
  \color{Red}{0} \leq \lfloor\frac{4t+5}{30}\rfloor  \leq  \color{Red}{2} 
\ \ 
%%\text{and} 
; 
\ \ \ 
-10 \leq -t+4 \leq 4 
\ \ 
\Longrightarrow 
\\ 
 -1+0-10 
\leq 
\lfloor\frac{4t-10}{30}\rfloor + 
\lfloor\frac{4t+ 5}{30}\rfloor 
-t +4 
\leq  
1 + 2 + 4
\ \ 
\color{Green}{\star} 
; 
\overset{\color{Blue}{\star}}{\Longrightarrow} 
\\ 
-11 
\leq 
11n 
\leq  
7; 
$$

---

so we have only two choices for $n$ ;

- $n=-1$, gives: 
  $$ -1+0-10 = -11 = 
  \lfloor\frac{4t-10}{30}\rfloor + 
  \lfloor\frac{4t+ 5}{30}\rfloor 
  -t +4 
  ; 
  $$ 
  which implies that: 
  $$ 
  4t-10 < 0 
  \ \ 
  ; 
  \ \ \ 
  4t +5 < 30 
  \ \ 
  ; 
  \ \ \ 
  -t+4 = -10 
  ; 
  $$ 
  so there is no possibilities for $t$ in this case.
- $n=0$, gives: 
  $$ 0 = 
  \lfloor\frac{4t-10}{30}\rfloor + 
  \lfloor\frac{4t+ 5}{30}\rfloor 
  -t +4 
  ; 
  $$ 
  which implies that: 
  $$ 
  -3=-(\color{Red}{1+2}) 
  \leq 
  -t+4 
  \leq 
  -(\color{Red}{-1+0})=1 
  ; 
  $$ 
  so the only possibilities for $t$ is: 
  $t=3, 4, 5, 6, 7$.
  Now you can check by-hand that only $\color{Green}{t=4}$ gives an answer.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26848/should-the-overuse-of-colored-text-be-discouraged/26858#26858

Comment: @miracle173 ; My dear miracle173 ; you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\lfloor{\frac{2x-1}{3}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\frac{4x+1}{6}}\rfloor=n$, where $n\in\mathbb Z$.

Hence, $5x-4=n$, which gives $x=\frac{n+4}{5}$.

Thus,
$$\lfloor{\frac{2n+13}{15}}\rfloor + \lfloor{\frac{4x+21}{30}}\rfloor=n,\tag{1}$$
which gives
$$n\leq\frac{2n+13}{15}+ \frac{4x+21}{30}<n+2,\tag{2}$$ which gives
$0\leq n\leq2$.

Now, for $n=0$ we get $x=\frac{4}{5}$ and a substitution in the original equation gives $1=1$,

which says that $1$ is the root.

$n=1$ gives $0=1$, $n=2$ gives $0=2$,

which says that the answer is
$$\left\{\frac{4}{5}\right\}.$$

Comment: are you sure that your last inequalities still contain the variable x?

Comment: @miracle173 I added something. See now please.

Comment: my quesion is, is it right that (1) and (2) contain the variable x or should that be n instead?

Answer (score 1):

[image]
The graph of the function $g(x) = \lfloor\frac{2x-1}{3}\rfloor + \lfloor\frac{4x+1}{6}\rfloor - (5x-4)$

Once we know $0 < x < 1$, we have $\lfloor\frac{2x-1}{3} \rfloor = 0$ and $\lfloor \frac{4x+1}{6} \rfloor = 0$. Thus $x = \frac{4}{5}$ is the only solution.

Comment: but how do we know that 0<x<1?

Comment: We want to find where the graph of $g(x) $ crosses the $X$ axis. From the graph, we see that it crosses the axis between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor x + 1/2 \rfloor = \lfloor 2x \rfloor$ identity . So $$\lfloor \frac{4a-10}{15} \rfloor = a-4 $$ Try $a = 0 , 1,2,3, \dots$ The only solution is $a = 4$ .